# showing a total score without the wrong answers

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I make an Android app but I've got one problem.

```
btnCalc.Click += (object sender, EventArgs e) => {
    totalScore = Convert.ToInt32(input1.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(input2.Text);
    total.Text = totalScore.ToString();
};
```

the game got 13 rounds. For every round there is one textbox.

It's a little game where you can hold the score over the game.
You have to say how many points you gonna get this round (always numbers)
but when you give the wrong answer the textbox text will be a: `×`

At the end I want to show the players who won.
How do I add these numbers without the wrong answers?

When you longclick on the textbox it will be a `×`.

Comment: Corrected English mistakes + removed useless words

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you had an array of all your Textboxes you could do something like the following:

```
        var items = new[]
        {
            new TextBox { Text = "10" },
            new TextBox { Text = "20" },
            new TextBox { Text = "x" },
            new TextBox { Text = "4" },
            new TextBox { Text = "x" },
        };

        var total = (from it in items where it.Text != "x" 
            select Convert.ToInt32(it.Text)).Sum();
```

Although that doesn't handle the case when the Textbox contains a value which isn't "x" and isn't a number. The following would probably be better:

```
var items = new[]
        {
            new TextBox { Text = "10" },
            new TextBox { Text = "20" },
            new TextBox { Text = "x" },
            new TextBox { Text = "4" },
            new TextBox { Text = "x" },
        };

        int val = 0;
        var total = (from it in items where Int32.TryParse(it.Text, out val)
                     select val).Sum();
```

Comment: and how can i conncect the textboxes to the array textbox?

Comment: Iterate through your Textboxes and choose whether to make them part of the array in some way (maybe by naming convention). Or just use all textboxes assuming none will contain numeric values that you don't need to use. Or just manually create an array with the Textboxes you know will need to be used. I was aiming for my solution to show how you could obtain a total from the textboxes you were interested in rather than how to select which textboxes to use.

Answer (score 0):

```
btnCalc.Click += (object sender, EventArgs e) => {
int input1 =0;
int input2 =0;
try{
   input1 = Convert.ToInt32(input1.Text);
}
catch{
// do nothing, the input1 will remain 0
}
try{
   input2 = Convert.ToInt32(input2.Text);
}
catch{
// do nothing, the input2 will remain 0
}

    totalScore = input1+ input2;
    total.Text = totalScore.ToString();
};
```

OR:

```
btnCalc.Click += (object sender, EventArgs e) => {
int input1 =0;
int input2 =0;

Int32.TryParse(input1.Text, out input1);
Int32.TryParse(input2.Text, out input2);

totalScore = input1+ input2;
total.Text = totalScore.ToString();
};
```